# How can I style these echo statements that make up my form

Tags: php, echo

I want to style these echo statements like a `login form`. How can I style these echo statements?

```
echo '<form action="login.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="ac" value="log"> '; 
echo 'Username: <input type="text" name="username" />'; 
echo 'Password: <input type="password" name="password" />'; 
echo '<input type="submit" value="Login" />'; 
echo '</form>';
```

Comment: Add the class to each form elements and define the CSS rules.

Comment: It's better to write HTML code outside the php tag since you are using no dynamic content. And then then you can easily design your HTML/CSS in better way.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following snipets

```
echo '<style>.testclassName{ text-align:right; }</style>';
echo '<form action="login.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="ac" value="log"> '; 
echo 'Username: <input type="text" name="username" class="testclassName"/>'; 
echo 'Password: <input type="password" name="password" />'; 
echo '<input type="submit" value="Login" />'; 
echo '</form>';
```

Comment: Didn't work for me unless I'm not attaching my stylesheet correctly but I doubt it